# Fix Jquery autcomplete search box issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

**JQUERY CODE**

```
        $('#search').keyup(function() {
              check_search();
            });
            $('#search').focusout(function() {
              check_search();
            });
            function check_search() {
              var search = document.getElementById('search').value;
              if (search.length > 0) {
                $('#search').removeClass('border-danger');
                var _token = document.getElementById('_token').value;
                $.ajax({
                  url:"{{ route('pro.claim.autocomplete') }}",
                  method:"POST",
                  data:{search:search, _token:_token},
                  dataType:"json",
                  success:function(result){
                    $('#suggest_name').html(result);
                    $('#suggest_name').fadeIn();
                  }
                });
              } else {
                $('#suggest_name').fadeOut();
                $('#suggest_name').html('');
                $('#search').addClass('border-danger');
                $('#search').focus();
              }
            }
            // GET VALUE
            $(document).on('click','#select_name',function () {
              document.getElementById('search').value = $(this).attr('value');
              $('#suggest_name').fadeOut();
            });
```

**HTML CODE**

```
        <div class="claim-searchbox">
                      <form id="search_business">
                        <div class="claim-searchInput">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                          <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search business page">
                        </div>
                        <div class="suggest-name" id="suggest_name"></div>
                        <div class="claim-searchSubmit">
                          <input type="submit" value="Find Business">
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
```

**LARAVEL CODE**

```
     // AUTOCOMPLETE
        public function autocomplete(Request $request)
        {
            $search = $request->search;
            $names = ProListing::where('name','like','%'.$search.'%')->get();
            $result = '<ul>';
            if (count($names) > 0) {
                foreach ($names as $name) {
                    $result .= '<li id="select_name" value="'.$name->name.'">'.$name->name.'</li>';
                }
            } else {
                $result .= '<li class="no-result">No Business Page Available</li>';
            }
            $result .= '</ul>';
            return response()->json($result);
        }
```

Problem Details:

- Everything works fine. fadeIn as requirements. But when I click to set the value to search box `$('#suggest_name').fadeOut();` not fadeOut and it shows again then after second time click it fadeOut. But I want to fadeOut div after first time click. get the value in the search box.

**Help me to solve this issue

Comment: Are you referring to the code block that is after the // GET VALUE comment?  If so, the click is triggered by clicking an element with an ID of #select_name but in your HTML there is no element with that ID.  Let me know if you're actually referring to the other $('#suggest_name').fadeOut() in the check_search function.

Comment: I will edit my content. I will provide laravel code. Please help me how to solve this @DougF

Comment: Is the click function executing?  If you put a breakpoint there, does it get hit?

Comment: click function executing but it shows again as the same result. But I am running code to fadeOut this div after getting the value in search box. In there, getting the value in the search box but didn't fadeOut it. Its fadeout after second time click @DougF

Comment: Looking at your Laravel code, I'm noticing you have a loop that is outputting an li element with an id of "select_name" but if the loop runs more than once then you will have many elements with the same ID, which causes problems.  I would suggest making the id a class instead and see where that gets you.

Comment: it returns same @DougF

Comment: It's difficult to debug the code like this.  Would you be able to post the markup after the Laravel code has been rendered to the browser?

Comment: Everything is work correctly. Just problem is that #suggest_name is fadeOut after 2nd time clicks on the desired value. I need to solve this issue like that its fadOut on first click  @DougF